# Save User progress in Quiz Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I have some models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    desctiption = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Question: {self.name}"


class Answer(models.Model):
    """Answer for one question. Can be correct or incorrect"""

    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Answer: {self.name}"


class Quiz(models.Model):
    """Quiz Model contain questions"""

    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    desctiption = models.TextField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Quiz: {self.name}"


class ProgressUserQuiz(models.Model):
    """Save user progress for any quiz"""
    ...
```

I can't understand how to structure ProgressUserQuiz.
For example. If user passed two questions in quiz and close a tab he can return to his last questions. And When he finished I want to add this in model.
How can I make it?tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Status flag for the questions

```
class ProgressUserQuiz(models.Model):
    status_opt = (
    ('answered',"Answered"),
    ('passed',"Passed"),
    ('closed',"Closed"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(choices=status_opts,max_length=50)
    something else like answer and marks?...
```

You can update this table after each question is done, and use this model to get the status. You can always Filter the data for questions of some quiz from these tables as well.

```
ProgressUserQuiz.objects.filter(question__in=list(quizinstance.questions.all())
```